# How do i add a string dollar amount in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have fields that have text like this

```
$4.00
$5.00
$55.90
```

and I want to add them in javascript to have a total of $64.90

I have this code

```
 var total= "";
 $("input:checkbox:not(.select_all):checked").closest("tr").each(function() {
    total += $(this).find(".amount").text().trim();
   });
```

My solution gives me this

```
 $4.00$5.00$55.90
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong

Comment: you'd have to strip off the `$` sign and parseInt them so you can do integer addition. Once something's a string in JS, it tends to STAY a string, so all you're doing is concatentation

Comment: @MarcB: Pretty sure you want to do parseFloat so you do floating point addition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're concatenating strings, you need to parse them as numbers first. You'll have to strip off the `$` to do that. You also want to initialize total to `0`, not to an empty string:

```
var total = 0;
$("input:checkbox:not(.select_all):checked").closest("tr").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).find(".amount").text().trim().replace(/^$/, ''));
});

// If you want total to be a string containing the `$` just convert it back:
total = '$' + total;
```

Comment: Or just put `+` instead of `parseFloat` ^_^ `+"10" === 10 //true`

Comment: @Derek: I think you're missing the point.  But I assume you say that because he's stripping the `$` and you're saying there's no need to do a `parseFloat` if you do that.

Comment: @vol7ron, I mean he can replace `parseFloat()` with `+()` because they  both turn string into numbers.

Comment: @Derek: yeah, you can also do `*1`, but that just obfuscates things.  It's a good comment, but might confuse Matt, who doesn't seem to understand that currency values are considered string and not numbers in JS